How to merge the cells with the same data in the table chart
In the table chart, each row will list all the column data. One use case is to merge/group the column cells into one combined cell for the same data/info so that it does not show repetitive data.
There is no such customization option in the table chart. Wonder if there is a way to transform the following example table chart/display.
from:
..........
abc | 123
..........
abc | 456
..........
abc | 789
..........


to: 
..........
    | 123
    ......
abc | 456
    ......
    | 789
..........  

